# ¿Cómo puedo generar códigos(números) secuencias en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Estoy trabajando en la base de datos MySQL y necesito generar un número consecutivo de acuerdo a cada "categoría secundaria" que se encuentra dentro de una "categoría principal" y un número consecutivo de cada producto de acuerdo con su "categoría secundaria".

He creado una vista para no complicarme con las relaciones entre las tablas, y que sea más fácil generar los secuenciales. Para su efecto ponga la siguiente tabla de ejemplo donde:

1. Primera columna es la categoría principal
2. La segunda columna es la categoría secundaria
3. En la columna final se encuentra el resultado deseado

Datos adicionales:

1. Una categoría secundaria pertenece solo a una categoria principal
2. Un producto pertenece solo a una categoría secundaria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
PSD: He intentado de varias maneras y no me funciona. Si me podrian ayudar con un ejemplo o una manera de como hacer.

Comment: Lo veo mas sencillo complicándote con varias tablas, ahora para que sirve realmente el numero de secuencia, ¿pasa si quitas un item, el siguiente saltaria ese valor o usaria el generado? Creo que lo mejor es usar un numero de orden dentro de la subconsulta

Comment: ¿Lo que presentas en la imagen es una tabla o es una vista o consulta tomada de varias tablas? Si es una tabla entonces tienes un claro error de diseño, ya que tendrías un sin número de productos repetidos. Necesitas al menos tres tablas: `productos, categorias` y una tercera tabla que gestione las relaciones entre productos y categorías. Todo lo demás que expones es una cuestión de lógica y por lo tanto debe ser tratada en la programación, no en el diseño de las tablas. Querer reflejar o resolver un problema de lógica de programación en el diseño de las tablas es un grave error.

Comment: para generar las secuencias en mysql debes crear una tabla y una funcion, si eso es lo que quieres hacer te puedo colaborar pero ese ejemplo que colocas esta muy enredado no entiendo porque se repiten los productos y tienen distinto secuencial

Comment: Es una vista generada a partir de las tablas de: categoría, cuenta (cat principal), producto, ingreso.  La imagen representa un reporte de todos los ingresos obtenidos. EL motivo de los números consecutivos es generar un reporte de todos los productos ingresados por lo tanto deben agruparse de tal manera.  Es decir que las tablas tienen una estructura bien diseñada. EL requerimiento es realizar el reporte con sus respectivos códigos (necesidad del cliente) asi como la imagen de ejemplo.

Comment: Lo de la imagen la columna 1 : pertenece a una tabla que se llama CategoriaPrincipal(id, codigo, nombre). La columna dos pertenece a la tabla de categoria (id, nombre). La columna que dice **producto** es obtenido a partir de todos los ingresos que se a realizado con ese producto (ese es el motivo de que se repite los productos).  La última columna es los códigos que espero generar para el reporte.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT iddetalleingreso,
@x:=CASE WHEN @class <> codcategoria THEN 1 ELSE @student+1 END AS 
codart,
@y:=codcategoria AS clset
FROM
 (SELECT @x:= -1) s,
 (SELECT @y:= -1) c,
 (SELECT *
FROM view_ingresoglobal
 ORDER BY codcategoria, fecha
) t ;
```

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu aporte! En el sitio intentamos tener respuestas con la mayor calidad posible. La idea no es mostrar solamente un fragmento de código, sino además explicar por qué esto funcionaría. ¿Qué hace este código? ¿Por qué o cómo solucionaría el problema expuesto en la pregunta? En [answer] podrás leer algunos consejos. ¿Podrías **[edit]** tu respuesta agregando algo más de información?

Answer (score 1):

Si no tienes inserciones muy masivas en las tabla, yo usaría un disipador algo asi:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `IncrementarCategoriaSTrigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `tabla_x`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
  DECLARE last_id INT DEFAULT NULL;  
  SET last_id = (SELECT max(CategoriaS)+1 FROM tabla_x WHERE CategoriaP = NEW.CategoriaP );
  IF (last_id IS NULL) THEN
       SET last_id = 1;
  END IF;  
  SET NEW.CategoriaS = last_id;
END
```

NOTA: **CategoriaP** es la categoria principal y **CategoriaS** la Secundaria, se supone que son valore numericos.

La idea es usando el valor de CategoriaP buscar el ultimo valor insertado de esa categoría (El que tiene el máximo valor) y sumarle 1. Luego reemplazamos el valor de CategoriaS por el valor calculado.

Te recomiendo indexar pro CategoriaS para calcular el max() mas rapidamente.

> Esto llegará tarde para tí, pero espero sirva para otros.